# Cannot use silent APNs with Firebase default authUI, always exception

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-push-notifications

In my Xcode Project I enabled APNs and in the Firebase Console I uploaded the correct APN Key. Still if I initiate the Phonenumber Login Process(with the prebuilt UI) it gives me an exception saying, that I need to add the URL-Type for the ReCaptcha.
How do I configure it to use silent APNs instead?

Error:

```
Exception: "Please register custom URL scheme 'com.googleusercontent.apps.*******' 
in the app's Info.plist file."
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the Info.plist
- Choose Open as Source code
- Add that to the list inside the :

  CFBundleTypeRole
            Editor
            CFBundleURLSchemes
            
                com.googleusercontent.apps.your-app-id-here

Full doc can be found here [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth)